# Is there any Spring Boot Data Reactive Starter targeting an embedded data store?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, embedded-database

I'm learning the ropes of Spring WebFlux with Spring Boot, by developing small demo applications.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the only [Spring Boot Data Starters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters) that are Reactive are the following:

- Cassandra
- Couchbase
- MongoDB
- Redis

Is there an option to use an embedded NoSQL store for development, like it's usually done with H2 for JPA?

Comment: I suggest a read of [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-mongo-embedded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I Understand you are looking for a NoSQL database that can be embedded in your application

you can use MongoDB as an embedded database please see the following link :

[spring boot with embedded mongo](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-embedded-mongodb)

[embedded MongoDB](https://flapdoodle-oss.github.io/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/)

I hope that will be helpful for you